# Drawing 2d Matrix on a Winform Component C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, drawing

I want to draw a 2 dimensional boolean array on a winform project. I want to put a filled rectangle where f[i,j]==1 and leave blank where f[i,j]==0.

My first question is, i'm using winform and i don't have much idea about which component can i do that on.I'm currently trying to do it on a panel but so far, i am not very successfull.

And i would also appreciate, if someone could give me a not complex sample of drawing a 2d array on a winform component, so i can understand it better, thanks

Comment: Could You show, what have You tried so far, please? Some basic code sample would help understanding Your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public partial class Print2DArrayForm : Form
    {
        public Print2DArrayForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //initial the matrix here
            matrix[0, 1] = true;
            matrix[1, 2] = true;
            matrix[1, 1] = true;
            matrix[1, 3] = true;
            matrix[2, 2] = true;
            this.Paint += Draw2DArray;
        }

        bool[,] matrix = new bool[3, 4];

        private void Draw2DArray(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int step = 50; //distance between the rows and columns
            int width = 40; //the width of the rectangle
            int height = 40; //the height of the rectangle

            using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
            {
                g.Clear(SystemColors.Control); //Clear the draw area
                using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    int rows = matrix.GetUpperBound(0) + 1 - matrix.GetLowerBound(0); // = 3, this value is not used
                    int columns = matrix.GetUpperBound(1) + 1 - matrix.GetLowerBound(1); // = 4

                    for (int index = 0; index < matrix.Length; index++)
                    {
                        int i = index / columns;
                        int j = index % columns;
                        if (matrix[i, j]) 
                        {
                            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(5 + step * j, 5 + step * i), new Size(width, height));
                            g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                            g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, rect);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, appreciated.

Comment: Glad I can help. The drawing code should be put inside the Paint event handler, so that the rectangles are not 'erased' when window is redrawn. code updated.